# Multiple Views Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, view

I am designing an iphone application and I need help structuring the program. I am new to xcode, but I'm still using xcode 3 because I don't have lion. The question I have pertains to using a view controller. My first question is how do I get rid of the view on the screen if I do not know which view is on the screen? My next question is how do I add the view I want to? I know i'm asking alot but I've tried a bunch of stuff and its not working.

Comment: You'll have better luck for most kinds of programs if you never think about adding and removing views, but rather about a hierarchy of view controllers.  I note that this URL < http://www.ithaca.edu/barr/Student/CS390/docs/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS.pdf > points to an older version of the view controller programming guide and might be more useful for Xcode 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of subviews currently displayed on the view like this:

```
NSArray *subArray = [self.view subviews];
```

or if you assign each one a tag when you add it, you can get a particular subview by its tag, ie.

```
UIView *someView = [self.view viewWithTag:100];
```

Once you've created an object for the view you want to work with you can simply call removeFromSuperview:

```
[someView removeFromSuperview];
```

Is that what you mean? Like removing buttons and images from the screen? Or do you actually mean you want to push/pop view controllers (like returning to the main menu from a game, etc)

Comment: I am having a lot of difficulty so I'm going to ask another question. If you could answer the next one that would be very helpful. Just go to my page and look... please!